# Why should one use a module bundler (webpack) over a task-runner (grunt)?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, webpack

In the past I've used a yeoman-generator Grunt for all of my dev tasks. Usually when working on a project I'll use it with compass to compile my scss, and then package and uglify my JS, optimize images, lint my code, and many other useful things.

Recently I've seen a trend towards people to use webpack instead of grunt plugins  for many of these tasks. Why is this? What is better about a module bundler in this regard?

Comment: personal preference.

Comment: There seems to be a strange trend in the node.js/javascript world to follow "best practices", and every time something new comes out, a group of developers/bloggers call it a "best practice" and a bunch of people jump on board.

Comment: Discusion seems closed to answer, so sorry for the messy message. For me webpack is not a personal preference. I do not use because webpack-dev-server or many nice sublimetext plugins. although in some cases it can substitute the use of tasks runners, in my current project I'm using in conjunction with gulp and they together are a winner team. The gold of webpack is the fact you can think on modules and it manages its dependencies.

Comment: On a font-end project you have an entry point (your JS code) that can require other JS files (modules), apply some CSS (module) that contains a font file (module), etc. Webpack allows to configure how do you want to handle all that module dependencies and build the your assets. You can create a single JS file with all the dependencies (yes, also containing CSS) or create different files, for example: app.js, vendor.js, style.css.

Comment: The way it builds assets is different (and initially something strange) than a task runner. With gulp or grunt you define the chain of steps while webpack works with two main concepts: loaders and plugins. For me it was initially weird see how my JS code has "require's" to CSS files, but now that brings me a lot of flexibility. FYI I'm just preparing an slideshow about webpack and a nice blog post: https://slides.com/acanimal/webpack

Answer (score 8):

I'm sure others have their reasons, but the biggest reason why I migrated to webpack (more specifically [webpack-dev-server](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)), is because it [serves your bundle from memory](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#content-base) (as opposed to disk), and its watcher will [recompile only the files you changed while reusing the rest from cache](https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#watch-mode) (in memory). This allows development to be much faster. What I mean is, while I am actively editing code, I can ctrl + s in Sublime Text, by the time I alt + tab to Chrome, it's already done rebuilding. I had a grunt + browserify + grunt-watch setup before, and it took at least 5 seconds to rebuild every time I save (that is after I've made bunch of specialized optimizations in grunt build). That being said, I still integrated webpack with gulp, so I got a task-runner for my project.

**EDIT 1**: I also want to add that the old grunt + LESS/SASS + browserify + uglify + grunt-watch setup didn't scale well. I was working on a major project from scratch. At first it was fine, but then as the project grew, it got worse every day. Eventually it became incredibly frustrating to wait for grunt to finish building every ctrl + s. It also became apparently that I was waiting for bunch of unchanged files.

Another nice little thing is that webpack allows you to require stylesheets in .js, which establishes coupling of source files in the same module. Originally we established stylesheet dependencies by using import in .less files, but that disconnected source files in the same module and established a separate dependency graph. Again all of these are highly opinionated, and this is just my personal opinion. I'm sure others think differently.

**EDIT 2**: Alright after some discussions below, let me try to offer a more concise and less opinionated answer. One thing that webpack does really well is that can watch, read, preprocess and update cache and serve with minimal amount of file I/O and processing. Gulp pipe works pretty great, but when it comes to bundling step, it inevitably ends up having to read all of the files from a temp directory including those unchanged. As your project grow, wait time for this step grows as well. On the other hand, webpack-dev-server keeps everything cached in memory, so the amount of wait time during development is kept minimal. However to achieve this kind of memory caching, webpack will need to cover from watch to server, so it will need to know your preprocessing configs. Once you have configured webpack to do just that, you might as well just reuse the same configs for spiting out builds other than dev server. So we ended up in this situation. That being said, exactly what steps you want webpack to do is still up to your personal preferences. For example, I don't do image processing or lint in my dev server. In fact, my lint step is a totally separate target.

Comment: The scaling issue you had with grunt looks to me like just a poorly setup watch task. Why would you have it rerun less/sass if you didn't change css? Maybe that's just a grunt thing? haven't had that issue with gulp.

Comment: @KevinB That's actually one of those "bunch of specialized optimization in grunt build" I was talking about. In practice, I much more finely tuned the build in order to keep the time down. But nethertheless, it was getting worse everyday and inevitably redundant. Gulp's pipe works great with uglify but node.js/common.js style packaging still required bundling all of the uglified sources on a temp directory and write to disk or integrate webpack. So my opinion being why going through all these troubles when webpack takes care all that with a few lines of config.

Comment: @KevinB I went from grunt + watch + uglify + browserify + express setup to grulp + webpack-dev-server. I didn't actually make a gulp + watch + ... setup before. So I'm curiously on your insights. How do you setup your dev build such that it rebuilds just the files that was changed? Like I said before, I can see how grunt-watch will work nicely with uglify, Babel, LESS/SASS etc, but when it comes to packaging step, wouldn't it need to read through the whole code base again to spit out a bundle? Googling didn't give me satisfying answers.

Comment: I usually had my processing output into a build folder, and i'd simply update it as files in the src folder changed. When it came time to bundle, i wouldn't need to re-build anything because it's already built in the build folder, i just package up that folder. I didn't need dev builds in the build folder thanks to source maps. It's been a month or two since i've worked extensively on front-end code, so i can't remember the specifics without digging back into it.

Comment: I do remember one important aspect.. One of the apps i was working on was a CMS that consisted of an angular frontend and a node rest api backend, developed as separate projects. In order to have my application look at an internal version of my api instead of production,  I added one more .js file that changed a config setting on one of the angular modules to change the api path in dev environment, meaning all I had to re-build for production was the index.html to remove the dev script.

Comment: Using grunt, livereload, and compass/scss I can get the same features in terms of having it compile only the scss/js I change on a watch task, rather than the entire bundle.

That said, I started working on my first wepback project last night and so far I love being able to bundle css and JS together and is worth the switch for me.

I'm still going to keep using grunt though, thought I may switch to gulp because I'm not finding as much documentation on webpack/grunt as I am webpack/gulp.

Comment: @KevinB thanks for getting back to me. So in your setup, during development, you load your preprocessed sources from (temp) build directory into browser. But bundle later for test/prod later is that correct? If that's the case, how do you deal with module loading and dependency resolution on client side before bundling? That's the step that I'm concerned.

Comment: @ChrisPawlukiewicz thanks for your reply as well. I think I have a similar question for you. How do you deal with module loading and dependency resolution on client side?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I use a mixture of npm and bower to pull in my dependencies and pull them together with browserify, any time a js change happens. So, on code changes I do have to wait a bit for a rebuild to occur, but I only have to wait on the js to rebuild, not css or images

Comment: @KevinB I see. I was wondering about your browserify step, so that's fine. Let's contrast the technical consequences of running webpack-dev-server with bunch of configs for preprocessing vs gulp-watch + preprocessing steps + browserify. Say you make changes to one .js file, that one file gets read, processed and written to disk in build directory. Then you invoke browserify step, which reads everything from build directory on disk (including unchanged files), bundle them and write to output somewhere to be served.

Comment: In case of webpack-dev-server, everything is cached in memory. When one file is changed, that one file is read from disk, processed and cached in memory. Bundle is updated by updating cache in memory for that one file. So this gives webpack-dev-server an edge in speed. But in order for this to work, you will have to configure webpack to give it all of your preprocessing rules, because it needs to work from watch to server all in memory. So in extension to that, a lot of people simply reuse the same webpack configs for other builds. I hope this is a better answer for OP's question.

Comment: @ChrisPawlukiewicz interesting. I looked at LiveReload, and it seems to serve equivalent feature set as webpack-dev-server if not much less. I think I can phrase my answer to you this way. You give LiveReload preprocessing configs, why is that? Because for an fast and efficient solution like that to work, it needs to watch and serve in one tool, therefore it needs to know your preprocessing rules. For webpack people, since we already made configs for webpack-dev-server, we just reuse the same configs for other build targets.